# Do I need both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js or is one of them enough?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Alright so after working with bootstrap in school it seems like a really good alternative to the other ways of creating responsive sites. I know that both files are put together differently, like one is like a wall of text and the other is more "user friendly" put up, but is there anything else different about them or do I just need one of them?

Comment: They contain the same code, so bootstrap.js during development (in case of errors you can easily browse where in the .js file the problem is) and bootstrap.min.js for release (as it consumes less space and hence less bandwith when the user opens the page for the first time)

Comment: Alright great, Thanks mate. I wish I could give you best answer thingy, but apparently that is not possible on comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to have both. You can use only bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.js. The thing is to reduce the script size that has to be rendered by the browser. so only we have minified versions.

Comment: as you know that compressed file is not as good as uncompressed one. its a matter of landing page (server capability)